# Updating single row in android widget remote listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-widget, remoteview

as the title states, is there any way to update one single row in a remote listview? 
I have got an application with a listview widget. When the user clicks a list view item, a service is started (via pending intent). This service updates model data and tell the views to refresh. But everytime the system updates an object it refreshes de whole view. I would like only one item to be updated.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you may want to check this example:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

Comment: I understood you but; I think it's not possible to update only one item without whole view. If you find out, please share with us too.

Comment: Thank you. I think so too. I dont mind to update the whole listview, the problem is that I am having this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260843/remote-listview-blinks-on-android-widget

Comment: OK I had that problem too. I fixed it. I'm outside right now. I'll write the solution of it when I'm back